# Is functional language wasting memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, recursion, functional-programming, imperative-programming

In general, I want to ask,

- if a problem can be solved by both imperative language way as well as functional language way, would functional language wasting memory, at least not saving memory, compare to imperative language, ***since***, function language heavily reply on recursion, and recursion push lots of memory stack ***?***
- and follow by above question, **from memory optimization point view**, if a job can be done in imperative language, it shouldn't (at least won't worse than) using functional language?

---

*The above questions, actually come from a algorithm question:*

> **reserve a stack without using additional space:**

```
void insert_at_bottom(node **stack, int data)
{
     if( isempty(*stack) ){
      push(stack,data);
      return;
     }
     int temp=pop(stack);
     insert_at_bottom(stack,data);
     push(stack,temp);
}  


void rev_stack(node **stack)
{
     if( isempty(*stack) ) return;
     int temp = pop(stack);
     rev_stack(stack);
     insert_at_bottom(stack,temp);
}
```

*The above question can be solved by using double recursions, in my opinion, even if it didn't use addition memory in the code, it actually "hide" those additional spaces in stack.*

---

Of course, my question more in general, you don't have to focus on above specific question.

Thank you for your thoughtful advise!

Comment: Read up on "tail recursion" and related concepts. Functional languages can make some interesting optimisations because programs can be subjected to mathematical proofs.

Comment: I know "tail recursion", which in this case, imperative language and functional language are **equivalence** (tail-recursion can be transfer to a loop). However, my question more focus on memory efficiency, ie. do a binary search in a huge array ...

Comment: My point was that tail recursion doesn't require extra stack memory, so just being in a functional language doesn't automatically mean using more resources.

Comment: I agree with you. In this case Func.Lang. NOT worse than imperative, but also not better than imperative, right?

Answer (score 3):

In a theoretical sense, no. You can always transform an iterative algorithm to a recursive one and vice versa. Assuming the same algorithm and implemented with tail-call optimization, the big-O of memory consumption would be exactly the same.

In a practical sense, maybe. The style of using immutable data structures in functional programming can take up a lot of memory.

IMO, using functional vs imperative programming is a matter of *style*. Use whichever one suits the code the best. And, if you need every last ounce of performance out of your machine, you can always write hand-optimized assembly.

Comment: Thank you! I agree it's style issue. say you are programmer in company (which you are not in a position to write a hand-optimized assembly), and from memory efficiency point view, if not necessary, you should tend to use imperative lang.?

Comment: If I were to decide on what language to use for a project (which I think is what you're getting at in your question), *and memory efficiency is a primary concern*, I would take into account the memory efficiency of *each language*, not *each style*. Like @IMSoP said, being a functional language does not necessarily mean more memory consumption, and being imperative does not necessarily mean less. I would instead recognize that lower-level languages (C, C++) give more control over memory consumption while higher level languages do not (Python, Java, Haskell).

Answer (score 2):

It's not that easy.

First, recursion, specifically tail recursion need not more memory than loops. The same holds for tail calls in general. A tail call, whether it is recursive or not, can always be compiled to a jump/branch instruction, *if* the target machine language allows this. Hence, a program in a functional language does not need to have bigger stacks than a comparable program in imperative languages by necessity.

On the other hand, in order to minimize side effects, functional programming prefers to deal with immutable data, in fact, *pure* functional programming allows *only* immutable data. Hence functional data structures tend to be more memory costly than mutable ones that are found in imperative languages.